# Hibernate- Liquibase throwing exception : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I am trying to generate changelog based on DB and Entity class

My Liquibase properties file is as follows

```
`url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
changeLogFile=classpath:/db/changelog/liquibase-changelog.xml
username=sa
password=password
driver=org.h2.Driver
diffChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase-outputChangeLog1.sql
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.weatherApi.cityData.City?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
`
```

when I execute

> `mvn liquibase:diff`

., the build is succeeded but the changelog generated is empty

it throws this error

> [WARNING] HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered,
> assuming application will be supplying connections [WARNING]
> HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply
> JDBC connections

I also use this dependency liquibase-hibernate5

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The answer on [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990213/hibernate5-hhh000181-no-appropriate-connection-provider-encountered-assuming-a) may work to resolve the first error for you.

However, it would be better to make separate posts for each individual error.

Comment: Did you solve it? If you did, could you post the solution please?

Comment: I found another post on the liquibase forums: https://forum.liquibase.org/t/error-when-running-diff-with-spring-boot-and-postgres/5284
says "it would always throw this error when running the diff command for generating migrations for new tables." as the accepted answer.

Comment: okay., I'll check out that one @tabbyfoo

Comment: I am also getting this error.

Comment: Yeah, for this one, I too haven't found a solution yet

Comment: Relevant github issue for this problem: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/381